# how to split an array into anther paired array

Tags: javascript

I want a very simple feature, I hope use short and beautiful code to do below

input:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

output:

```
[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8],[9,10]]
```

how to do this in javascript

Comment: Do you want to handle odd number of element in the array?

Comment: `JSON.parse('['+[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].toString().replace(/(\d+,\d+)/g, '[$1]')+']')` heheh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function splitPairs(arr) {
  var newArr = new Array(Math.round(arr.length / 2));
  for (var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; i+=2) {
    newArr[i>>1] = [arr[i], arr[i+1]];
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/PRC9R/)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different flavor that changes the array in place (assumes an even number of array entries):

```
var orig = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
for (var i = 0; i < orig.length; i+=2) {
    orig[i/2] = [orig[i], orig[i+1]];
}
orig.length /= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two lines:

```
function cut(ar)
{
    for(var i=0,l=ar.length,tmpar=[];i<l;i+=2)tmpar[tmpar.length]=[ar[i],ar[i+1]];
    return tmpar;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7yd26/3/

And with odd number of element in the array, it works too: http://jsfiddle.net/7yd26/4/